# Html5 game with Dashcode

Tags: javascript, html, dashcode

I'm new to Dashcode and I got quick question here:

Say I have a Html5 game (javascript) already, is it possible to integrate it into Dashcode (I don't know if I have myself understood) ~ 
I know I can add widget made with Dashcode into a ebook (using iBooks author) so it will be cool if I can add a "html5 widget game" into the book ~

Hope someone familiar with Dashcode can help me here, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working and it is quite easy.

Just create a folder and copy the required info.plist and Default.png in~

Then copy all the game files and resource in and rename the launch html to main.html

Finally rename the folder to xxxx.wdgt and that's it :)